# resharper and microsoft naming conventions. How should I adjust? WPF/Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, naming-conventions, resharper

Started using ReSharper and have some issues along. I got most of the stuff figured out but can't decide what to do with:

1. VS automatically creates Window_Loaded, Button_OnClick and so on. Resharper says there should be no underscore. How can I fix all those?
2. How Should I name controls and windows in WPF? I name them as btnSubmit, wndMain, etc but obviously this is not what preferred by ReSharper. Is SubmitButton and MainWindow better?

prefixing worked for me in the past since I can see items sorted in collections but maybe it's wrong? Any suggestions will be helpful. I'm going through tremendous pain with all this StyleCops etc :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Question 1)

Just disable as shown below.

```
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
        private void btnCreateChannel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
// ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
        {
            SetupChannel();
        }
```

Question 2)

Follow Microsoft naming convention -> [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Conventions are pretty much up to you. The only place where they really matter is where the framework bases itself on these conventions. i.e MVC EF 4.1 ...

Many can argue a long time about prefixes. Many will tell you that with the tools we use today, the prefixes are not important and can be discarded.

But in some instance I still love to use prefixes like `p_` and `m_` just because I like to work with local copies and never with parameters.

This also a matter of preference. In some cases having `string strName = string.Empty;` can be quite repetitive.

You can edit the ReSharper conventions to reflect what you would like to enforce throughout your project.

This is great when team share these settings. It truly helps keep a consistent style. ReSharper's default conventions are great I often suggest to stick with those and modify them as you go.

Answer (score 0):

If your tools are telling you conflicting things then turn one of them off. It doesn't matter which, though it may well be easier to turn off the ReSharper rule than changing the way Visual Studio names events.

The important thing with coding standards is that you are consistent across the project and across developers. There's no "right" way. Go with what's easiest to implement.